# Как перенести WooCommerce с Open Server на VPS?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, openserver, vps

Обычно я всегда разрабатываю сайты/проекты локально, на Open Server. Потом переношу всё на VPS. И это работает. Действительно, все просто - перенос файлов, базы, настройка конфига сайта (если он есть) и, в ообщем, всё. Джумла, опенкарт, самописные проекты - переносятся без проблем.

Но с WooCommerce это не так.

Я на Open Server установил WordPress и WooCommerce, настроил, добавил инфу, плагины, настроил плагины, изменил код части файлов - проделал большую работу.

Далее перенес файлы и БД на VPS, изменил конфиг. Делал все по инструкциям, коих в инете море. Менял имя сайта и в админке и в БД.

И всё равно сайт на VPS загружается некорректно.

По ссылкам не может найти страницы. Стили не подгружает, плагины не работают.
Пытался использовать плагины клонирования. Та же история - все криво.

**Как перенести woocommerce с Open Server на VPS?**

Вроде такая простая задача - файлы+база, но не работает. Может есть хорошая, детальная инструкция? Ставить и настраивать всё с нуля - это ещё на неделю работы (

Comment: Пермалинки обновляли ? Панель администрирования -> Настройки -> Пермалинки -> нажимаем просто сохранить.

Comment: Обновлял Адрес WordPress (URL) и Адрес сайта (URL)

Comment: Попробуйте обновить пермалинки, как як написал выше, а также проверить на стройки .htaccess если сервер на Apache. 
Обычно не переходит по ссылкам при переносе какраз таки по этой причине.

Comment: Конечно есть такая инструкция, с объяснениями проблем. И прямо здесь, на SO ru: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Comment: @Иван "Обновлял Адрес WordPress (URL) и Адрес сайта (URL) " - прямой путь к неработающему современному сайту, с сериализованными данными. Подробнее читайте мой вопрос-ответ по ссылке в предыдущем комментарии.

Comment: "Подробнее читайте мой вопрос-ответ по ссылке в предыдущем комментарии". Прочитал, понял что не так все просто. Использовал плагин Duplicator. Все прошло без ошибок. Но сайт не корректно работает. Главная страница один в один как и на локалхосте. Видно, что все подключилось. Вижу что плагины работают. Но переход по любой ссылке и...страница не найдена.

Comment: Значит, у вас неправильно сделаны ссылки, что даже duplicator их не воспринял. Покажите конкретику

Comment: Сайт https://bit.ly/2JfxJ4r. Расположение всех файлов в папке www/html_files. Файл .htaccess присутствует и стандартный.

Comment: Я посмотрю вечером обязательно

Comment: Посмотрел. А после переноса duplicator вы сохранили по-новой структуру постоянных ссылок? Какая она сейчас?

Comment: " А после переноса duplicator вы сохранили по-новой структуру постоянных ссылок?" Я не очень понимаю о чем вы. Если вы говорите о Настройки->Постоянные ссылки, то там изначально я ничего не менял. Потом менял, пробовал разные варианты.  Только что заменил на простые и заработало. Но ссылка вида page_id=6 как то не то. На локалхосте product-category/tovary/udobreniya/simulyatory-rosta/ - что намного лучше. (

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75479/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-).

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что я бы проверил это открываются ли эти страницы с админки с редактора. Открываешь страницу в редакторе и нажимаешь посмотреть страницу. Если открылась, значит проблема в чпу! Перейдите к настройкам чпу в админке и проверьте что там стоит. Попробуйте поменять на дефолтные настройки.

Вторым делом, нужно проверить правильно ли указаны в меню ссылки. Возможно ссылки вы проставили в меню, а потом поменяли их порядок, или же поменял плагин чпу если он присутствует.

В любом случае, если страница открывается с редактора, то дело в чпу, если нет, то дело в перенаправлении самого сервера. Настраивать придется через файл htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно есть такая [инструкция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562), с объяснениями проблем. И прямо здесь, на SO ru.

У вас проблема в неправильном переносе сайта.

> Обновлял Адрес WordPress (URL) и Адрес сайта (URL)

Это прямой путь к неработающему современному сайту, с сериализованными данными. Подробнее читайте мой вопрос-ответ по ссылке выше.

Полсе переноса не забудьте сохранить заново структуру постоянных ссылок. Это, кстати, напоминает сделать Duplicator. Зайдите в "Настройки"->"Постоянные ссылки" и нажмите кнопку "Сохранить изменения".